# How to translate this MATLAB for loop in R?

Tags: r, matlab

I want to convert this MATLAB for loop into R:

```
p=24;
t=455;

for i=1:p-1
    Y=[Y; y(:,p-i:t-i)];
end;
```

The Y matrix has a dimension 4x432 and y matrix is 4x455.

The R code I tried is:

```
for (i in 1:p-1) {
Y<- rbind(Y, y[,p-i:t-i])
}
```

However, I am getting an error which says: **Error in y[, p - i:t - i] : subscript out of bounds.**

Based on the output in MATLAB, the Y matrix must become a 96x432 matrix after running the above for loop.

I can get to the same result in R by running these quite long set of codes:

```
yyy1 <- as.matrix(yy[,23:454])
yyy2 <- as.matrix(yy[,22:453])
yyy3 <- as.matrix(yy[,21:452])
yyy4 <- as.matrix(yy[,20:451])
yyy5 <- as.matrix(yy[,19:450])
yyy6 <- as.matrix(yy[,18:449])
yyy7 <- as.matrix(yy[,17:448])
yyy8 <- as.matrix(yy[,16:447])
yyy9 <- as.matrix(yy[,15:446])
yyy10 <- as.matrix(yy[,14:445])
yyy11 <- as.matrix(yy[,13:444])
yyy12 <- as.matrix(yy[,12:443])
yyy13 <- as.matrix(yy[,11:442])
yyy14 <- as.matrix(yy[,10:441])
yyy15 <- as.matrix(yy[,9:440])
yyy16 <- as.matrix(yy[,8:439])
yyy17 <- as.matrix(yy[,7:438])
yyy18 <- as.matrix(yy[,6:437])
yyy19 <- as.matrix(yy[,5:436])
yyy20 <- as.matrix(yy[,4:435])
yyy21 <- as.matrix(yy[,3:434])
yyy22 <- as.matrix(yy[,2:433])
yyy23 <- as.matrix(yy[,1:432])
yyy <- rbind(yyy1, yyy2, yyy3, yyy4, yyy5, yyy6, yyy7, yyy8, yyy9, yyy10, yyy11, yyy12, yyy13, yyy14, yyy15, yyy16, yyy17, yyy18, yyy19, yyy20, yyy21, yyy22, yyy23)
Y <- rbind(Y, yyy)
```

I know that this is not the most efficient way of doing it, that is why I want to translate the above MATLAB for loop into R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need ()

```
for (i in 1:(p-1)) {
Y<- rbind(Y, y[,(p-i):(t-i)])
}
```

guess what, `1:4-1` is not 1, 2, 3

BTY, your question is wrong. y should be 4 x 455.

Comment: It does not work. It still gives me the same error.

Comment: yes, you are correct. y should be 4 x 455. I have then corrected my posted question. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: Hello, your suggestion actually worked. I was able to obtain the 96x432 Y matrix. The y matrix in the above MATLAB code, i actually assigned it as the yy matrix in my R work environment. I was then indexing/accessing the wrong matrix in my earlier code. So, the correct code following your suggestion is:  for (i in 1:(p-1)) {
Y<- rbind(Y, yy[,(p-i):(t-i)])
}